# Java- Searching for a string in text file, then print line

Tags: java, string, file, search, text

I am writing a code where the user can search a text file for a particular string, (case insensitive) and it prints the entire line where the string is found. My code snippet is here:

```
public static void search() throws FileNotFoundException
{
Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
int fieldNumber = 0;



if ( fieldNumber == 0 )
{
    System.out.println("Enter field value to search for: ");
    String fieldValue = input.next();
    if ("orange".equalsIgnoreCase(fieldValue))
    {
     // Here is where I am stuck. 
       {

       }
```

Comment: Just an observation...you are getting the input from the user in your `fieldValue` variable, but you don't appear to use that. Instead, you are comparing against the string literal "ford". What you really want is something like  `lineFromFile.toLowerCase().contains(fieldValue.toLowerCase())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    try
    {
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
        String str = str.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter search ");
        Num = input.nextInt();

        if ( Num == 0 )
        {
            System.out.println("Enter search for: ");
            String Value = input.next();

            while (file.hasNextLine())
            {
                final String lineFromFile = file.nextLine();
                if(lineFromFile.contains(Value))
                {
                    System.out.println("file.txt");
                    System.out.println(lineFromFile);
                    break;
                }
```

Comment: Does this print the whole line that the string is on?

Comment: @Paul The sample code should give you an idea about the search. I leave the rest for you to figure out.

Comment: Post your input file and your input, please.

Comment: you mean the .txt file?

Comment: I have to take a look at sample data and your input.

Comment: Updated the Complete program!

Comment: I can work with this, thank you very much! @GaneshThiagarajan

Answer (score 0):

When the Scanner reads a line, it gives you a String.

So let's look at the String API.
http://www.google.com/search?q=java+string+api

The method I'd take a look at:

```
indexOf(String str)
```